# How do I calculate percent of whole within a Postgres JSON array?

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I've got several million rows in a PostgreSQL 9.3 table, and I'm struggling to calculate aggregate statistics.

Here are the columns:

`object_id | date | column_with_json_data_in_key-value_format | bunch_of_irrelevant_columns`

There is one row for every object_id/date combo. There are approximately 70 keys in the JSON column, but any given row only contains ~5-20 keys.

**Across all object_id's, for each key, what is the daily average fractional value?**

1. Within each row, calculate the value of a particular key divided by the sum of all values for all keys for that particular row
2. If a key doesn't appear in a row, treat it as having a value of 0 for that row
3. Group the results by date
4. Calculate the average value for each key

So my desired output is a table with the following columns:

`date | key1_name | key1_fractional_average | keyN_name | keyN_fractional_average`

I tried this query for a single row, but it's not working correctly:

```
SELECT value2, total, (value2/total * 100) AS percent FROM
    (SELECT SUM(value) AS total FROM
        (SELECT CAST(CAST(value AS text) AS integer) FROM json_each((SELECT json_column
            FROM original_table
            WHERE primary_key = 1)::json)) as table1) as total_table,
    (SELECT CAST(CAST(value AS text) AS integer) AS value2 FROM json_each((SELECT json_column
            FROM original_table
            WHERE primary_key = 1)::json)) as value_table
```

For this particular page_id/insight_date row, the query returns the following:

```
value2 | total | percent
------------------------
1;          4;         0
2;          4;         0
1;          4;         0
```

The columns `value2` and `total` are correct, but the `percent` column incorrectly shows 0's instead of the correct 25%, 50%, 25%.

Unfortunately, because JSON is a fairly new type in Postgres, googling hasn't turned up many examples. I'm thoroughly confused here.

Comment: The problem is not that JSON is a new type. The problem is that it is not a substitute for [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, these JSON values are much, much better stored as JSON. I mentioned JSON as a new type because it took me forever to figure out that in order to cast to integer, I first have to cast it to text. Normalizing them into separate tables would be a nightmare because there are many JSON columns, and it's very infrequently accessed. These particular queries will only be run for deep analysis, so slow performance is just fine, as long as I can figure out this query structure in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are dividing integers, which gives you integer division and discards the remainder.  You need to cast them to a fractional type.

```
value2::double precision/total::double precision * 100
```

You may want to do the cast farther down in the query.